# How to reset admin password in sysPass?

Tags: passwords, reset

I am self hosting the password manager sysPass: https://github.com/nuxsmin/sysPass

I lost the password to the only admin account but I still have the master password / key and full access to the database. Unfurtunately sysPass does not have a password reset function.

I know that sysPass is using BCrypt with 10 iterations and the master password to create the password hash for each user.

There are several fields that apparently needs an update to do that:

user_pass - varbinary - content starts with: $2y$10$...

user_mPass - varbinary - content starts with: def50200...

user_mKey - varbinary - content starts with: def10000def50200...

But I don't know how to  use that information to create a new password for my admin user.

Does know how to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

- encrypt your new password you want to change using bcrypt(10 rounds)
- log into your database (go to table : usrData)
- convert your newly generated hash to binary (use hexworkshop)

[how to generate binary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kECjH.png)

- copy the text generated on the left side
- replace the "user_pass" field value with the new binary string you got from hexworkshop
- you can login with the new password

Answer (score 0):

I've been digging into this. Though frankly, I'm not sure it would apply to password resets, here's how I would generate those hashes, initializing the database for a new deployment. With `/var/www/html`, syspass installation path:

```
<?php
require_once('/var/www/html/vendor/defuse/php-encryption/src/Core.php');
require_once('/var/www/html/vendor/defuse/php-encryption/src/Crypto.php');
require_once('/var/www/html/vendor/defuse/php-encryption/src/DerivedKeys.php');
require_once('/var/www/html/vendor/defuse/php-encryption/src/Encoding.php');
require_once('/var/www/html/vendor/defuse/php-encryption/src/Exception/CryptoException.php');
require_once('/var/www/html/vendor/defuse/php-encryption/src/Exception/WrongKeyOrModifiedCiphertextException.php');
require_once('/var/www/html/vendor/defuse/php-encryption/src/Key.php');
require_once('/var/www/html/vendor/defuse/php-encryption/src/KeyOrPassword.php');
require_once('/var/www/html/vendor/defuse/php-encryption/src/KeyProtectedByPassword.php');
require_once('/var/www/html/vendor/defuse/php-encryption/src/RuntimeTests.php');
use Defuse\Crypto\KeyProtectedByPassword;
use Defuse\Crypto\Crypto;

$userLogin  = isset($argv[1]) ? $argv[1] : "admin";
$userPass   = isset($argv[2]) ? $argv[2] : "blabla";
$masterPass = isset($argv[3]) ? $argv[3] : "blabla-11-chars-long";
$salt       = isset($argv[4]) ? $argv[4] : "be5570f6809a460bcbc5625fd3274ee0184c4164fe8707a8147dfcc84ac5";

$keypw = $userPass.$userLogin.$salt;
$mkey  = KeyProtectedByPassword::createRandomPasswordProtectedKey($keypw)->saveToAsciiSafeString();
$k     = KeyProtectedByPassword::loadFromAsciiSafeString($mkey)->unlockkey($keypw);
$mpass = Crypto::encrypt((string)$masterPass, $k);

print "ADMIN_MKEY=$mkey\n";
print "ADMIN_MPASS=$mpass\n";
?>
```

Call that script with you username as a first argument, password in second, masterpassword third and a salt (that would be the `generatedSalt` from your `config.xml`).

The `user_mPass` and `user_mKey` should be initialized with the `ADMIN_MPASS` and `ADMIN_MKEY` returned.

While the `user_pass` can be generated using something like:

```
htpasswd -bnBC 10 "" "<your-admin-password>" | tr -d ':\n'
```